# Connection reset with duplicate query parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, firewall

Is there anything that could cause a connection reset when duplicate query parameters are passed to a page?

http://test/?test[]=1&test[]=2 Causes a connection reset
http://test/?test[]=1 Works

Everything works on my development server, but the same code causes a connection reset on the production server. The only configuration difference I know of is that the development server is running Ubuntu Natty while the production server is running Lucid. But it's very common to pass arrays in the URL this way in PHP and I've never experienced it causing a problem before.

Could it be a firewall on the clients network doing this?